# Error 'x' must be numeric?

Tags: r, histogram, numeric

I keep getting an error message saying that "x" must be numeric for the hist() output, how can I fox this?

```
length= function(nsims,n)
{


    x <- as.numeric(seq(2,nsims))
    t <- lapply(x,abovex) 
    return(t)
  }
hist(length(10,10))
```

Note:

```
abovex = function(n) {
    if (n<=0){ return(cat("n must be greater than 0"))}
    else
  step = c(1, -1)
  S = c(0, cumsum(sample(step,n, prob=c(.5, .5), replace=T)))
  above=sum(S[S > 0])
  return(above)

 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `length` function returns a list, not a numeric vector. `length` is also a Primitive function, so you might want to choose a different name to avoid confusing yourself.

Use `sapply` instead of `lapply` if you want the result *s*implified to a vector.

```
length_sims <- function(nsims,n)
{
  x <- seq(2,nsims)
  t <- sapply(x,abovex) 
  return(t)
}
hist(length_sims(10,10))
```

Your function could also be shortened to:

```
length_sims_short <- function(n) sapply(seq(2, n), abovex)
hist(length_sims_short(10))
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way of doing it using the lapply function?

Comment: @user3347124: no. `hist` requires a vector, not a list. If you don't want to change your `length` function, then wrap it in `unlist`: `hist(unlist(length(10,10)))`. But this is very, very poor coding practice, IMHO.